# Positioning Graphics draw

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to draw some polygons and lines usinng `e.Graphics.DrawPolygon` (or DrawLine). But I have a little problem specifying the coordinates where to draw. I am drawing onto a `PictureBox` using its Paint event. The elements draw correctly relatively to each other (creating the required final picture), but seem always to draw in the upper-left corner of the PictureBox. When creating the points to draw, when I just try to multiply the coordinates, it draws it at the same place but bigger (size is multiplied, instead of location coordinates).
Here is my code:

```
//some for loop
{
//getting the coordinates
Point toAdd = new Point((int)xCoord, (int)yCoord); // creating the point from originaly a double, here i tried to multiply..
tmpPoints.Add(toAdd); // tmpPoints is a List<Point>
}
points.Add(tmpPoints.ToArray()); //List<Point[]>


drawBuffer = points; //saving to a public List<Point[]>
points.Clear();
this.Invalidate();
```

here part of the pictureBox1_Paint method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < drawBuffer.Count; i++)
        {
                //some other stuff like deciding which color to use, not very important
                Brush br = new SolidBrush(polyColor);
                e.Graphics.FillPolygon(br, drawBuffer[i]);
                brush.Dispose();
        }
```

I have checked using breakpoint, the coordiinates are the same ratio (what was 100 pixels wide is still 100 pixels wide), they are at coordinates like x 3000 and y 1500, but it just draws itself in the upper-left corner. When i multiply the coordinates 3 times (see the code for the place where i multiplied), it draws at the same place but 3 times bigger (doesn't make sense after checking the coords...)
So, my question is - how do I set the location correctly, or is there any other way to do this?
Like this (I know, this is nonsense, just an example)

`foreach(Polygon poly in e.Graphics)
{
poly.Location = new Point(poly.Location.X * 2, poly.Location.Y * 2);
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you multiply

`poly.Location = new Point(poly.Location.X * 2, poly.Location.Y * 2);`
you are doing a stretch operation when you add

`poly.Location = new Point(poly.Location.X + 50, poly.Location.Y +50);` you are doing a translation operation.

Answer (score 3):

When you multiply the coordinates of the points, they're scaled around the point (0, 0), the top-left corner of the canvas:

[image: Polygon scaled around (0,0)]

In order to scale it around its center (and I suppose you expected it to work this way), you need to calculate some kind of center of the polygon. For simplicity, it can be even an arithmetic mean of the coordinates, on X and Y axes respectively. If you already have the coordinates of the center, translate the coordinates of every point by **a reversed vector** made from the center coordinates (this is how it would look like if you drew it after this operation - the polygon's center is in the center of the coordinate system):

[image: Polygon is in the center of the coordinate system]

Now, do your scaling:

[image: Polygon scaled]

and move it **back** by the vector of polygon's center coordinates:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to shift **everything** without modifying the stored coords then just translate the graphics before drawing:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(100, 100); // shift the origin somehow
        // ... draw the polygons as before ...
    }
```